# How to remove the Welcome watermark on this page?

Tags: css

If you go to my website 
you'll see a big watermark with "Welcome on it" How do I remove this?
I've tried using inspect element and I get span as the element
so I do in additonal css

```
#span{
display: none;
}
```

but it does not seem to be working.

[image: problem]

Comment: I don't see what you are saying : https://screenshots.firefox.com/CLtClbfmNfxlqTUG/173.79.218.105

Answer (score 0, accepted):

#span would reffer to an element with id="span" you need to refer the correct element to achieve this:

```
 .intro-item span{display: none;}
```

Read a css manual on selectors for more about this.